# No module named "requests" when trying to use google OAuth2 with Docker

Tags: python, docker, google-authentication

I am trying to use google OAuth for my web app. To do so I installed the packages google-api-python-client and google-auth in my venv and during my Docker build(from a requirements.txt). Despite this when I run my app it can't find the requests module, complaining that:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "debateit", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 23, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

The import is as follows:

```
from google.auth.transport import requests
```

and is used like:

```
idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), app.config["GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID"])
```

Other imports such as the id_token.verify_oauth2_token work fine.

I checked my docker build and it says I have included google-auth correctly:

```
Installing collected packages: ... google-auth, httplib2, google-auth-httplib2, google-api-python-client
Successfully installed ... google-api-python-client-1.7.3 google-auth-1.5.0 google-auth-httplib2-0.0.3 httplib2-0.11.3 ...
```

I can clearly see the google.auth.transport.requests module when I look in the venv, it just doesn't work in the app itself.

What am I missing? What could cause this module to not be found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I found out what was wrong - within the google.auth.transport.requests module they try to import the library "requests". I did not have this library installed. I have done so and it works now.

The guide I was following: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth did not mention that you need to install this library. I misunderstood what the import for requests in the requests module was supposed to do.

Comment: AppEngine documentation: 10 minutes writing the code, 3 hours setting configurations...
For the backend-auth example, you need to install both "requests" and "google-auth". Like every external lib (yes, google-auth is external), you should pip-install them to `lib/` (some people use `libs/`). Best way is to have a `requirements.txt` file with each lib in a new line ("requests", "google-auth") and then call `mkdir lib`, `pip install -t lib/ -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Most people use virtualenv to be sure that there are no differences between the local pip/python versions and app-engine pip/python versions. If you have problems with the pip-install, try adding a setup.cfg file with:
`[install]\nprefix=`
AppEngine's documentation also doesn't mention that you need to add the following to your app.yaml:
`libraries:\n- name: ssl\n  version: latest\n`
This installs some local library for the ssl of the auth calls (not sure which). I find it funny that you cannot install the `google-auth` itself by configuring the app.yaml file...

Comment: (stackoverflow won't let me write newlines in comments, so I marked them with '\n')

Comment: Worked like a charm on google-auth==1.30.0 and python 3.7. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As reported in [the documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.transport.requests.html), it should be more likely like:

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

credentials.refresh(request)
```

But for your purpose I'll suggest:

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
```

then change the following from:

```
idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), app.config["GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID"])
```

to:

```
idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, Request(), app.config["GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID"])
```

---

It was an error because inside the path `google.auth.transport.requests` there is no function or class which is named `requests`.

My suggestion is based on the line

```
idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), app.config["GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID"])
```

which show us that you use a class named `Requests()` which is present into `google.auth.transport.requests` as you can see in [the documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.transport.requests.html).

Comment: Unfortunately I updated my code to match your suggestion and ran into the exact same issue, no module named requests. I added bash to my web image and checked that the package is there - it is. Something is going wrong along the line here...

Answer (score 1):

`pip install requests`

It seems like `google.auth.transport.requests` uses `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was answered but you can quickly install those libraries globally by the running the command :

```
pip install google-auth
```

Here is how to install pip or installing the libraries in local virtual environment if someone doesn't want to install them globally:
https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/